# IOError when loading data file to plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, genfromtxt

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

x,y = np.genfromtxt('D:\Tanjil\Python\directory\Heat Available Datas.csv',unpack=True , delimiter=',',skip_header=0)

plt.plot(x,y,'ro--'),

plt.ylabel('Power Input (kW)'),

plt.xlabel('Speed(rpm)'),

plt.show()
```

but this code shows this error message :

```
File "C:\Users\bad_tanjil\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 151, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode)

  File "C:\Users\bad_tanjil\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 501, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)

IOError: D:\Tanjil\Python\directory\Heat Available Datas.csv not found.
```

Comment: Make sure that the file you want to open is in the location that you specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your path with `/` rather than `\`. That's how you specify the path. In a string `\` acts as an escape character. You can also use `\\`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
'D:\Tanjil\Python\directory\Heat Available Datas.csv'
```

To

```
'D:\\Tanjil\\Python\\directory\\Heat Available Datas.csv'
```

Or

```
(r'D:\Tanjil\Python\directory\Heat Available Datas.csv')
```